# How to find a partial derivative with respect to a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, linear-control

Let we have a $2\times2$ matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2\\a_3&a_4\end{bmatrix}$, a $1\times2$ matrix $C$, and a $2\times1$ matrix $X$. How can we calculate derivative of $CAX$ with respect to matrix $A$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Write explicitly the product $CAX$. It will be a function of $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$.

Comment: The "derivative" (the differential, really) of a linear function is itself.